# VIM: set format of line number

Tags: vim

I am thinking of using the `asdfg` column keyboard to replace the number keys when jumping. The best solution I think of is to add a layer of Leader mapping:

After pressing the Leader prefix, the relative number becomes the corresponding letter. The user only needs to press J or K after pressing the corresponding button to jump.

But I found that the official documentation does not give a method to set the line number format. I remember that some plug-ins can display the git status of each line in front of the line number. Has the format of the line number been modified? Has anyone had similar development experience?

thanks.

I just find `set numberwidth=xx` to set width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has the format of the line number been modified?

`:help 'signcolumn'` used to have only three possible values. It semi-recently gained a new one: `number`, which tells Vim to display signs in the number column if there is one:

```
set signcolumn=number
```

Your, problem, now, is managing signs: `:help sign-support`.